# What's the most rational way to connect a Tesla Powerwall to a preexisting solar install?

Tags: wiring

Say a residence has an existing grid-connect solar install that (at a very high level) looks approximately like this:

[image]

If an AC Powerwall 2 is added to this setup, while simultaneously doubling the installed solar capacity, what is the most rational configuration?  Is it:

**Option 1**
[image]

**Option 2**
[image]

**Option 3**
[image]

...or perhaps none of those?  Is there a standard/optimal configuration that should be used in this scenario, or are there different possible setups with different pros and cons, and if so what do they look like?

Comment: What does the manufacturer have to say about this? What are your objectives and metering regime - one meter, two meters, smart meters, feed-in-tarriff? What does your electrical code say? You may not be *allowed* to put the battery between the panels and the meter, for example.

Comment: Do you want to be able to run "islanded" while the power is down? That's definitely an electrical code issue.

Comment: @pjc50 - Manufacturer documentation is [here](https://www.tesla.com/sites/default/files/pdfs/powerwall/Powerwall_2_AC_Owners_Manual.pdf).  It appears to suggest Solar -> Inverter -> Meter box, with the Powerwall only connected to the meter box, though I'm not understanding why you'd do it that way?  To answer the other questions, assume one meter (non-smart), and a feed-in tariff that's about 40% of the retail tariff.  I'm unsure about the electrical code; are there some standard constraints that it's reasonably safe to assume?  If so, use those.

Comment: I'm not sure there are sensible defaults; crazy local rules may apply e.g. http://www.iflscience.com/policy/illegal-power-home-solar-panels-florida/ . In a single-meter setup you do as Tesla suggest and put it on the house side of the meter, connected directly to the distribution panel. (The Tesla diagram is clearer than yours because you have three or more arrows running into and out of the "meter box", and no distribution panel)

Comment: (I'm not sure whether the tesla device is capable of arranging to use its batteries in preference to the grid, or whether it's *just* a backup solution?)

Comment: Note that the Powerwall 2 is designed to work with a Powerwall-specific external transfer device (the Backup Gateway).  Could you redraw your diagrams to take that separation into account?